What does "off" mean in "for the winter when they're off in their southern migration breeding areas"?
From Warning system helps protect migrating whales from ship strikes off Bay Area coast

"So we're seeing a lot of prey, mostly anchovy and type[sic] of fish. That
school is[sic] and is really healthy and nutritious for whales. There's
also krill and it happens to be quite close to the coast right now.
And the whales are here because they're here feed[sic] to fatten up for the
winter when they're off in their southern migration breeding areas,"
Stock explains.

Can 'off be omitted without changing the meaning?

I believe there's a word missing in the first sentence. The second sentence also seems mistranscribed, and the fourth.

Citations without attribution is plagiarism. Please cite your source IN the question. If possible also include a link to said source.

@Mari-LouA: Plagiarism entails alleging authorship over something you didn't in fact author (which, indirectly, means you're not attributing it to the correct source). This isn't plagiarism, it's just a lack of sourcing that would help understand the surrounding context. The absence of a cited source is not irrefutable evidence of plagiarism, that's a logical fallacy.

@TimR OK, I have corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

@Mari-Lou A Anyway, I added the source.

@TimR Those sentences are indeed mistranscribed. What she actually says is, “So we're seeing a lot of prey, mostly anchovy, a type of fish that schools and is really healthy and nutritious for whales. There's also krill, and it happens to be quite close to the coast right now. And the whales are here because… they're here to feed, to fatten up for the winter” (the video cuts her off here, so the last part containing the off bit isn’t actually heard).

@Janus Bahs Jacquet Here is an example from Oxford Learner's Dictionaries-Sarah's off in India somewhere.

@Mr.Wang I’m not sure what the purpose of that link is? I’m aware how off works, and I know that it’s perfectly fine and normal how it’s used here. TimR pointed out that the places where you wrote ‘[sic]’ in the quote from the article all sound ungrammatical; I watched the video and listened to what the speaker actually said, and I concluded that whoever transcribed her speech for the article did so incorrectly, and the text in the article doesn’t match what she actually said. What I wrote is what the speaker actually said.

@Janus Bahs Jacquet Sorry, misunderstood.

We can use the adverb 'off' to discuss movement (to) or location (in or at) away from some notional 'here' or place, often implied. The whales are here feeding, but later they will be off (i.e. gone way from here) in their southern migration breeding areas.
If you omit 'off' you also remove the additional meaning 'having gone away from here'.

off adverb
away from a place or position, especially the present place, position,
or time
He drove off at the most incredible speed.

Off (Cambridge Dictionary)

We used to say "Be off [with you]!", which is now usually "Go away!" But I don't think it ever was or ever will be "Be away [with you]!" or "Go off!" Just idiomatic preference, I guess.

@FumbleFingers - 'Be off with you, you ruffian!' is what I would like to say, sometimes, to people.

That's the trouble with being born a century too late! I sometimes wish I'd been born 4 or 5 centuries earlier, so I could say Learn thou of FumbleFingers manly fortitude! without sounding too weird!

The listed meaning does not work in conjunction with "in [location]". "He is off to the dentist's office" is fine, but "He is off in the dentist's office" is not. The linked source does not contain an example of "to be off in", and the only usage I can find online relates to a different meaning of "off", e.g. "something is off in my relationship" or "the gloves are off in this discussion".

@Flater - it works fine. It’s so fascinating because, with this book, it’s like the principal character is absent. Rose is off in France, and everything about this book sort of revolves around her, but it’s seen from such a unique perspective. (book review)

@Flater “He’s off in the dentist’s office” indeed doesn’t work, but that’s because this use of off implies spending a significant amount of time in a location that is seen as being away from the ‘default’ (i.e., where he spends his life, or where a narrative takes place), and a visit to the dentist doesn’t qualify. You wouldn’t say, “He’s in the dentist’s office” either, unless you were focusing on his physical location inside the room (e.g., if searching the building for him); normally you’d use at rather than in.

@Flater Compare the very common expression, “He’s off at uni(versity)”, which implies that he is there for an extended period of time (university takes several years), and also that the university is some distance away from where he grew up or previously lived (or, if it’s a parent speaking, where they live) and that he is living there (perhaps on-campus).

An addendum to Michael Harvey's good answer.
"off" has a deictic aspect.
If the oceanographer is in northern waters and explaining why there are no whales present:

There are no whales here. They are off in their southern breeding grounds.

The whales are "away (from here)".
But if the oceanographer is actually in the whales' southern breeding grounds and is studying their mating behavior, he would not say:

We're studying the mating behavior of the whales here, while they are off in their southern breeding grounds.

Even though the whales are away from where they normally are when not breeding, we would not use off in that utterance if we are where the whales are.

Your source reads as if someone has transcribed spoken English, which is usually more flexible then written.
The use of "off" suggests 2 things to me.

"In the old days", before everyone had TV, it was common to hear commentaries on horse races on the radio. The commentator would need to fill in while the horses were waiting to start, and then say "They are off..." once the race started. So these whales are off...
People talk about being "off on holiday", and also "the off season": as others have mentioned, this is on line with people or animals being somewhere else. IMHO the use of "off" is fine.


Dinged your answer for a few  things: 2 should be "two", "then" should be "than", and the connection to horse racing isn't clearly explained. What does the race commentator mean by saying "They're off!"  ?

@Timr This explains the symbol '2'. If you feel that Arabic numerals are new fangled ("something these young fellers bought back from the Crusades"), I can understand that you'd find a radio commentary difficult.
